# What is the right way or correct 'Event' to write a code on hideURLbar

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the bookmark to jump from the First page to a specific section of another page

but this **another page** (Second Page) includes the following code :

```html
<script type="application/x-javascript">
  addEventListener("load", function () {
   setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
  }, false);

  function hideURLbar() {
   window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }
</script>
```

**This code** is causing to reload the page when I jump from the First page to this page (another page). So first, it takes me to the bookmark section (as expected) but within in microseconds, it reloads.

When I remove this script then it doesn't reload if I am landing on this page through the First page with bookmark.

But I think this script is important when using a smartphone and I think it is set on a wrong event which is "load" or it is written in a wrong way by the previous developer.

So my question is what is the correct way to write this script on the correct event and the purpose of the script still sever without affecting bookmark functionality happening from the First page to this page.

Comment: The script you are showing us here does not reload the page! All it does is wait until the entire page is loaded and then after 1 millisecond it scrolls to 0px from top and 1px horizontally. (that might looks to you like a reload cause it doesn't stay at the bookmark you would like)

Comment: Thanks for explaining me, So does it mean I can remove this script as I believe that whenever if a page is loaded in a normal way it will show the top (except when it is triggered through other pages bookmark). I don't know why the previous developer put this code when in default situation it does the same thing.